# Flutter Datetime month value

Tags: datetime, flutter

I want to print the month value like 06 but it writing 6. How solve this problem.

```
DateTime tarih=DateTime.now();
String ay=tarih.month.toString();
print("ay:$ay");
print("tarih:$tarih");
```

I/flutter (17892): ay:6

I/flutter (17892): tarih:2020-06-20 13:10:51.425817

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import intl package to use various date formats

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Then use 'MM' to get date as 06:

```
DateTime tarih=DateTime.now();
String ay = DateFormat('MM').format(tarih);
print("ay:$ay"); //Prints 06
print("tarih:$tarih");
```

It also supports other formats

```
DateFormat('EEE d MMM').format(tarih) //Returns Sat 20 Jun
DateFormat('dd/MM/YY').format(tarih) //Returns 20/06/20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  DateTime tarih=DateTime.now();
  int ay=tarih.month;
  if (ay <= 9) {
    print("ay:0$ay");
    // You can make a variable equal to "ay:0$ay" (e.g [06])
  } else {
     print("ay:$ay"); 
    // You can make a variable equal to "ay:$ay" (e.g [6])
  }
}
```

This will work by checking if the number needs a 0 in front of it and then add the zero and if not will not add it.